# How do you declare the types for a component that uses set function?

Tags: typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

This example is perfectly working but the types won't work well yet to compile it.

I have the following:

```js
function SpotlightElement(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements['spotLight']) {
  return (
    <group ref={group}>
      <SpotLight ref={**set**} />
    </group>
  )
}

export default function MovingSpot() {
  const [depthBuffer, setDepth] = useState()
  return (
    <>
      <DepthBuffer ref={setDepth} size={512} />
      <SpotlightElement **depthBuffer**={depthBuffer} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is my doubt...how do I make typescript understand that the ref for the **SpotLight** component is retrieved from the **set** function? As of now it assumes is brings the component itself instead of the function that configures it: Type 'Dispatch' is not assignable to type 'Ref | undefined'.

Also, if the props attribute from the SpotLightElement function is being declared as JSX.IntrinsicElements from 'group' which will be the correct type to use instead, because now the **depthBuffer** property apparently doesn't exist in the spotLight props defined in three-types.d.ts:

*Property 'depthBuffer' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Node<Group, typeof Group>, NonFunctionKeys<{ position?: Vector3 | undefined; up?: Vector3 | undefined; scale?: Vector3 | undefined; ... 4 more ...; dispose?: (() => void) | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }>> & { ...; } & EventHandlers'.*

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you create a sandbox showcasing your issue?

Comment: ``:THREE.SpotLight`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Advised by the team behind *drei* I did use THREE.SpotLight. I had to change the  component for the  provided by three in addition to adding the SpotLightProps type and here is the final piece:

```
type SpotLightProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['spotLight'] & {
  depthBuffer?: DepthTexture
  attenuation?: number
  anglePower?: number
  color?: string | number
}

const vec = new Vector3()
function SpotlightElement(props: SpotLightProps, ref: React.ForwardedRef<SpotLightImpl>) {
  const group = useRef<THREE.Group>(null!)
  const [light, set] = useState<THREE.SpotLight>(null!)
  const viewport = useThree((state) => state.viewport)
  useFrame((state) => {
    group.current.position.lerp(vec.set(state.mouse.x, state.mouse.y, 0), 0.1)
    light.target.position.lerp(vec.set((state.mouse.x * viewport.width) / 2, (state.mouse.y * viewport.height) / 2, 0), 0.1)
  })
  return (
    <group ref={group}>
      <spotLight ref={set} />
      {light && <primitive object={light.target} />}
    </group>
  )
}
```